# RegEx match everything between multiple matches over multiple lines

Tags: regex

This is how my string/file looks like:

```
== Section 1 ==
Content of section 1. Bla bla bla
this = tha
numbers bla bla

== Section 2 ==
Content of section 3. Bla bla bla
this = tha
numbers bla bla

== Section 3 ==
Content of section 3. Bla bla bla
this = tha
numbers bla bla
```

Now i want to match the title of the section (in between '==') and the content of the section itself.

This matches the sections itself: `/== (.*) ==/g`
Then I tried to match the parts in between, but this where I get stuck. I changed to allo newline for dots and made the first match ungreedy: `/== (.*?) ==(.*?)/gs` but the second match now either matches nothing `(.*?)` or everything `(.*)` but i want to match "until the next match" or the end of the line.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^== (.+?) ==((?:\r?\n(?!== ).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of the string
- `==`  Match literally
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char as least as possible for the title
- `==` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2** for the content

  - `(?:\r?\n(?!== ).*)*` Match the whole line if it does not start with `==`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GtWobU/1)

Or the other way around without the leading newline

```
^== (.+?) ==\r?\n((?:(?!== ).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2DPEy7/1)

Comment: thanks, the first one is good enough for my purpose.
however I have a followup question: why does this not work: `/^== (.+?) ==\r?\n((?:\r?\n(?!== ).*)*)/gm` to omit the linebreak after the `==`?

Comment: @JanOechsler In that case, you are matching 2 newlines, here `\r?\n` and here `(?:\r?\n`  which is not present in the example data.

Answer (score 1):

As you have **2 line breaks** between each block, you may use this regex:

```sh
/^==.*==\r?\n(?:.+\r?\n)*.+/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9SrKXu/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `==`: Match `==`
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `==`: Match `==`
- `\r?\n`: Line break
- `(?:.+\r?\n)*`: Match 0 or more lines containing 1+ of any characters
- `.+`: Match 1+ of any characters